# algoritmo en python, lista con 100 numeros sin que se repitan y obtener la suma de pares e impares

Tags: python, funciones

Me piden lo siguiente:

> Realizar un algoritmo que genere 100 numeros aleatorios del 1 al 200.
>   El sistema debe guardar estos sumeros aleatorios en un areglo de 100 
>   posiciones, en este arreglo no se debe repetir ningun número generado.
>   Luego de llenar el arreglo con los 100 numeros, realizar la suma de los 
>   numeros pares e impares y de acuerdo al resultado, mostrar el mensaje 
>   cual fue mayor (la suma de los pares o la suma de los impares), en caso 
>   que el resultado sean iguales, mostrar los dos resultados de las sumas.

La tematica es funciones y arreglos, entonces empecé así:

```
from random import randrange
from time import sleep

numeros = []
validacion = []
longitudx = 10
longitudy = 10

def lista():
    numeros.append([])

def imprimir_numeros():
    longitud = len(numeros)

    for i in range(longitud):
        print(numeros[i])

def validacion(numero):
    for i in range(longitudx):
        for j in range (longitudy):
            if numeros[i][j] == numero :
                return False
                break
    return numero

numeros = randrange(200)

def llenar_numeros():
    x = 0
    while x < longitudx:
         y = 0
         while y < longitudy:
             numero = validacion(randrange(200))
             if numero:
                 numeros[x][y] = numero
                 y += 1

        imprimir_numeros()
        print(" ")
        print("  ")
        x += 1

def sumatoria():
    for numero in numeros:
        if numero // 2 == 0:
            suma_pares = numero
        print(" La suma de los numeros pares es " + str(suma_pares) )

        elif numero // 2 !=0:
            suma_impares = numero
            print(" La suma de los impares es " + str(suma_impares))

llenar_numeros()
sumatoria()
```

A la hora de correrlo me da varios errores, necesito ayuda para llenar la lista con los numeros y que luego me identifique los pares e impares para luego hacer la sumatoria de ellos.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con tu código? revisa este enlace para [Aprender como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), la idea es ayudarte con un problema específico, mas no hacerte la tarea

Comment: Lina ¿Por que intentas usar una lista bidimensional y no simplemente una lista unidimensional para almacenar los números? ¿Que restricciones te imponen? Lo digo porque para ver si un numero esta en la lista o no usa `if numero in numeros` y recorre el array con `for n in numeros` no usando len  + range + indices (es ineficiente y poco pythónico). También puedes usar el builting `sum` para la suma. Para ver si un numero es par o no se usa la división entera `//` sino el modulo `%`.  el primer error que hay es que con `numeros = randrange(200)` cambias tu variable `numeros`(lista) por un entero.

Comment: Si la en la lista los elementos no se pueden repetir, y no te importa el orden en que se almacenen, creo que sería más conveniente usar un `set`.

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma podrías generar la lista de números sin que se repita, quizás no es la más optima pero puede ayudarte a darte una idea.

```
def generate_random_list_int():
    numbers = []

    while True:
       number = random.randrange(1, 201)
       if number not in numbers:
          numbers.append(number)
          if len(numbers) == 100:
              break
    return numbers
```

Sacar los números pares e impares es también sencillo:

```
numbers = generate_random_list_int()

pares = sum(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, numbers))
impares = sum(filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, numbers))
```

Esta tampoco es la forma mas optima de sacar la suma, pero nuevamente te haces una idea. Se usa el operador `mod` o `%` el cual retorna el residuo de una división, si este da 0, pues es un numero par, de lo contrario es un número impar, y se usa la función `sum` que viene integrada con python para sumar los números dentro de una lista.

Cualquier duda comenta.

Answer (score 0):

> Realizar un algoritmo que genere 100 numeros aleatorios del 1 al 200.
>   El sistema debe guardar estos sumeros aleatorios en un areglo de 100
>   posiciones, en este arreglo no se debe repetir ningun número generado.
>   Luego de llenar el arreglo con los 100 numeros, realizar la suma de
>   los numeros pares e impares y de acuerdo al resultado, mostrar el
>   mensaje cual fue mayor (la suma de los pares o la suma de los
>   impares), en caso que el resultado sean iguales, mostrar los dos
>   resultados de las sumas.

Puedes utilizar un set, en lugar de una lista. Un set se define como una colección desordenada de elementos únicos. Por tanto jamás en un `set` se va a repetir ningún elemento.

Utilizando su método `add` podemos llenarlo de **elementos únicos** sin realizar la comprobación de que el elemento esté en el Array.

```
from random import randrange

numeros = set()


while len(numeros) < 100:
  numero = randrange(200)
  numeros.add(numero)

print(numeros)

suma_pares = sum([n for n in numeros if n % 2 == 0])
suma_impares = sum([n for n in numeros if not n % 2 == 0])

mayor = 'pares' if suma_pares > suma_impares else \
        'impares' if suma_impares > suma_pares else \
        None

if mayor:
  print('La suma mayor es la de los números: ', mayor)
else:
  print('Los pares e impares suman lo mismo')

  print('Suma pares: ', suma_pares)
  print('Suma impares: ', suma_impares)
```

[Ejemplo funcionando](https://repl.it/MdEy/0)

Answer (score 0):

La función sample de random te permite generar una población sin repeticiones.

```
import random
population = random.sample(range(1, 200), 100)
sum_even_numbers = sum(x for x in population if x % 2 == 0)
sum_odd_numbers = sum(x for x in population if x % 2 != 0)
if sum_even_numbers > sum_odd_numbers:
    print('Suma pares mayor:', sum_even_numbers)
elif sum_even_numbers < sum_odd_numbers:
    print('Suma impares mayor:', sum_odd_numbers)
else:
    print('Sumas iguales')
    print('Impares:', sum_odd_numbers)
    print('Pares:', sum_even_numbers)
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una forma muy sencilla y eficiente, simplemente cuando vaya generando elementos aleatorios del 1 al 200 va analizar si no esta en la lista, si no está lo agrega a una lista de pares o impares, y cuando hallan sido 100 elementos en total, (que se agrega a una lista aparte), evalúa la suma máxima e imprime.

```
from sys import stdin
import random
def main():
    lista=[]
    pares=[]
    impares=[]
    while len(lista)<100:
        numero=random.randint(1,200)
        if numero not in lista:
            lista.append(numero)
            if numero%2==0:
                pares.append(numero)
            else:
                impares.append(numero)

    resultado=(max(sum(pares),sum(impares)))
    if resultado==pares: print('la suma de pares es la mayor')
    else: print('la suma de impares es la mayor')
main()
```